# How to run cron job automatically without any action in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have used wp_schedule_event but this is not full my requirements.It can be triggered on any click or reload the page.
How can i create cron job that automatically trigger on a specific time without any action in wordpress.

Comment: You need to trigger a CRON task on your server. Apache servers cannot execute a task at a specific time without action. There are not processes running in the background like on other types of servers.

Comment: Does your host have cPanel on it? You can create your own schedule cron to run a php file from there? Happy to share details if you need them.

Comment: I have rest api that can be triggered  on specific time and dump the data into WordPress database @ZecKa yes i can create real CRON task on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way, as far as I know is to use the `cron` ability of your server. 
For example, in Red Hat based distributions such as CentOS, `crontab` files are stored in the `/var/spool/cron` directory, while on Debian and Ubuntu files are stored in the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory. Open `crontab` file and write something like:

```
* * * * *    php /var/www/html/your-website/your-cron.php
```

This will execute the file `your-cron.php` every minute.

**Note**: Although you can edit the user crontab files manually, it is recommended to use the `crontab` command.